# Cauchy's principal value of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

**INTRODUCTION TO MY PROBLEM:** let's suppose that we have: $\delta[g(x)]$, where $g(x)$ is a smooth function such that $g(x)=0$ at some points $(x_k)_{k=1,...,N}$ and $|g'(x_k)|\neq0 \; \forall k=1,...,N$. Well, using distributions formalism (i know how to show that) we get a formula to express: $$\delta[g(x)]=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\delta(x-x_k)}{|g'(x_k)|}$$

---

**THE PROBLEM ITSELF:** let's now suppose we have: $PV[g(x)]$, where g(x) is such that can be written like: $g(x)=\frac{\text{something}}{\text{something els}e}$ where $(\text{something else} = 0)$ at some points $(x_k)_{k=1,...,N}$. Is there a fancy way to express the principal value in relation to those points like happened with $\delta[g(x)]$?

---

**MY ATTEMPT:** I was trying to do the job with the test function: $PV[g(x)]\approx PV\left[\dfrac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{N}(x-x_k)} \right]$ $$\left\langle PV[g(x)] \; \middle| \;  f(x)\right\rangle=PV\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{\prod_{k=1}^{N}(x-x_k)}\right)=\lim_{\epsilon\;\rightarrow \;0^+}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{x_1-\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{\prod_{k=1}^{N}(x-x_k)} \, dx \;+ \int_{x_1 + \epsilon}^{x_2-\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{\prod_{k=1}^{N}(x-x_k)} dx+...+ \int_{x_N +\epsilon}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{\prod_{k=1}^{N}(x-x_k)} \, dx\right]$$ At this point i think i should proceed doing these two steps:

1. For each integral i would take off many of the terms from denominator. For example: $$ \int_{-\infty}^{x_1-\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{\prod_{k=1}^{N}(x-x_k)} \, dx \; \rightarrow \; \int_{-\infty}^{x_1-\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{(x-x_1)} \, dx \\[6ex] \int_{x_1 + \epsilon}^{x_2-\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{\prod_{k=1}^{N}(x-x_k)} \, dx \; \rightarrow \; \int_{x_1 + \epsilon}^{x_2-\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{(x-x_1)} \, dx$$
2. Then i would regrup all terms pair-by-pair. So that each pair gives me the principal value of one of the $(x_k)$, and eventually: $$PV[g(x)]= \sum_{k=1}^{N}PV\left(\frac{1}{x-x_k}\right)$$

---

**FINAL TOUGHTS:** anyway, i think i'm in the realm of sci-fi since i cannot really imagine why i would change the dominators like that.. Moreover, i found an example where: $$\require{cancel} \cancelto{\text{**EDIT: commited a typo.**}}{PV\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right) \; \rightarrow \; \frac{1}{2}\left[PV\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right) - PV\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\right]} \\[6ex] PV\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right) \; \rightarrow \; \frac{1}{2}\left[PV\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right) - PV\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\right]$$ What happened here? It seems i was almost there with my intuitive path, but that minus sign really stunned me...

Comment: $1/(x^2+1)$ is a bounded function ... no need for principal value there! Even if it is in french, I recommend you to look at the book of Laurent Schwartz about distributions, were a lot of these kind of questions are discussed

Comment: @LL3.14 Thanks for your consideration.. i'll surely give a look to your suggestion, but i committed a typo in my question that was edited.. my example intended to be about $PV\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)$:

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: @LL3.14 Thanks again for your fast response! I originally tought about partial decomposition, but that imply some sort of 'linear property' for principal value that i'm not really sure about. In fact: $PV\left[\frac{1}{x^2 - 1}\right]=PV\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+1}\right)\right] = \text{linear property(?)}=\frac{1}{2}\left[PV\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right) - PV\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right) \right]$

Comment: Is that true? Or i should use some other properties or definitions to show that?

Comment: Furthermore, the partial decomposition only holds for functions like: $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, where both $(p, \, q)$ are polynomials.. but what about functions like: $\frac{f(x)}{q(x)}$ where only $(q)$ is a polynomial and $(f)$ whatever enough smooth function?.. The formula i provided for expressing the deltas of a function seems much more general..

Comment: @LL3.14 Anyway, i managed to show $PV\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+1}\right)\right] =\frac{1}{2}\left[PV\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right) - PV\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right) \right]$ using the definition of principal value as distribution.. even if only for function $g(x)$ that can be expressed as $\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{\alpha_k }{(x-x_k)}$, your contribution was essential to me, so if you add your comment as an answer, i'll accept it. However, i you want to continue your discussion for more general cases, i will really appreciate.